# virtualbox-5.0 : Depends: libvpx2 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, dependencies

I'm trying to install Virtualbox 5.0 in my ubuntu machine

```
Linux federico 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run `apt- install` I receive this error:

```
root@federico:~# apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 virtualbox-5.0 : Depends: libvpx2 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed this link without success.

[virtualbox-5.0 won't install on ubuntu-server 14.04.4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270003/virtualbox-5-0-wont-install-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-4)

Any Suggestion?

Comment: `apt-get update` often fixes apt problems: the repository may have been updated.

Comment: Don't work as root; use `sudo`. It is safer.

Answer (score 0):

From Software Sources Enable all repository under **Ubuntu Software** (Canonical + community...), just type `gksu software-properties-gtk`

then type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Install `libvpx2` :

```
sudo apt-get install libvpx2
```

Install [virtualbox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270011/153195)

Comment: [Apparently nautilus-gksu has not been in the Ubuntu repositories since 12.04.](https://askubuntu.com/a/314732/243060)